# Is it viable to run multiple containers on Google Compute Engine VM Instances running Container Optimized OS?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

Looking at the [Google Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers) it states that "You can only deploy one container for each VM instance."

However, in the [Getting started with Cloud Endpoints for Compute Engine with ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-compute-engine-docker) tutorial it describes running two containers, one for the ESP and one for the API.

The tutorial documents doing this by hand so is not exactly a blueprint for production but it seems odd to me that this approach should be presented given the aforementioned limitation.

The fact that you can only specify one container in the `gce-container-declaration` means that to automate deploying multiple containers you'd need to use another approach.

Indeed elsewhere in the [Container Optimized OS documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#advanced) it states:

"For advanced scenarios where you can deploy multiple containers and configure Docker options using cloud-init, you can create a Compute Engine instance with your choice of Container-Optimized OS image then proceed to configure it as needed."

Given this apparent inconsistency in the documentaion, is it viable to run multiple containers on GCE COS or should I be looking at other options such as Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is possible to deploy multiple containers to Container Optimised OS but it's complicated procedure.**

To quote again the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance):

> For advanced scenarios where you can deploy multiple containers and
> configure Docker options using cloud-init...

If you use console or deployment manager it's not possible to deploy more than one container, **but if you create a [config file](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#using_cloud-init_with_the_cloud_config_format) and use [cloud init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) you can deploy many containers to that instance**.

I would recommend using [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) for that - it was designed specifically for that purpose and you can manage the containers in a much easier way.

Comment: Thanks. This is the conclusion I have come to.